# Add polygons as Map Layer using geemap folium and fill color based on categorical variable

Tags: folium, google-earth-engine, geemap

I am importing geemap folium with

```
import geemap.foliumap as geemap
```

and creating a map using

```
Map = geemap.Map()
```

It works perfectly for the images I add as layers. I would like to overlay geometries that I have in a GeoPandas dataframe, and set their fill color based on another column in the same dataframe.

I attempted to do so by using

```
fc = geemap.geopandas_to_ee(gdf[['geometry','Category Column']])
Map.addLayer(fc, {}, 'Category Name')
```

This adds the overlay of the geometries, but they all have the same fill color. I couldn't find a visualization parameter or other method to solve this. If anyone can help, I would greatly appreciate it.